# Select random values from <p-dropdownitem> dropdown using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm not able to select random values from a drop down which has below html code.

```
<div class='ui-dropdown-items-wrapper'>
   <ul class='ui-dropdown-items ui-dropdown-list' role='listbox'>
      <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport class='cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport'>
         <div class='cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper'>
            <p-dropdownitem class='ng-tns-c14'>
               <li role='option' class='ui-dropdown-items ui' area-label="apple">
                  <span class='ng-star-inserted'>apple</span>
               </li>
            </p-dropdownitem>
            <p-dropdownitem class='ng-tns-c14'>
               <li role='option' class='ui-dropdown-items ui' area-label="Banana">
                  <span class='ng-star-inserted'>Banana</span>
               </li>
            </p-dropdownitem>
            <p-dropdownitem class='ng-tns-c14'>
               <li role='option' class='ui-dropdown-items ui' area-label="Mango">
                  <span class='ng-star-inserted'>Mango</span>
               </li>
            </p-dropdownitem>
         </div>
         <div class="cdk-virtual-scroll-spacer"></div>
      </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried below code,but not working..Can any one please help me to select random values from above HTML code.

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@role='option']"));
Random rand = new Random();
int list= rand.nextInt(options.size());
options.get(list).click();
```

Comment: Can you also show us an image of how that html looks? The HTML, you provide use, looks like plain text nothing selectable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified XPath and it is working fine but before performing dropdown selection i need to click on drop-down then only li/span list are loading.

## Modified XPath as :

```
//label[@for='year']/../div//li[not(contains(.,'--select--'))]
```

## Final Code:

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[@for='year']/../div//li[not(contains(.,'--select--'))]"));
 Random rand = new Random();
 int list= rand.nextInt(options.size());
 options.get(list).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with this XPath?

```
 List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p-dropdownitem/li[@role='option']/span"));
 int size = options.size();

 options.get(new Random().nextInt(size)).click();
```